# Hiding java code

Tags: java

I would like to give an executable jar file to my client and I have a code in it to expire after a certain time. But if the client uses some decompiler and reads the class file, he can modify and make the code to work Is there any way I can stop this from happening.

Can I use deleteOnExit() or some other technique ???

Comment: Use an [obfuscator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code).

Comment: You could copy the jar at runtime to a temp directory and start another JVM with it, then from there delete the original. But realistically no, so you could explain us what you actually need to do.

Comment: That would make it harder, but not guaranteed impossible for the client to reverse engineer the code and crack it.

Comment: @Jesper it usually makes it more costly to deobfuscate the code than to buy it.

Comment: I do not know of a way to make it 100% unreadable. Maybe wrap it in an exe file. Disassembly is worse to read than obfuscated code.

Comment: Thank you guys. I've tried using an obfuscator but, most of my code has lots of string manipulations and its pretty easy to decode it. I should probably try wrapping it in an exe file.

Comment: @bhanu: some obfuscators include string encryption which are trivially breakable, but may dissuade casual decompilation

Answer (score 7):

If you are so worried someone will crack your software, you'll need to use some kind of client/server architecture where your client can only log in to a webpage in your servers.

Any code can be cracked if there's someone who really wants too. Of course, most of the time its simply not worth it.

Answer (score 3):

Best solution for this is PaaS (platform as a service)..
put your logic on a server as server-app and let client-app communicating with server-app through web-service or any other way .. this is the best real solution..

BTW: using obfuscation cannot protect your code.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not possible in any kind of environment currently in use. If you are so worried about the client stealing your code, it might be good to reevaluate your relationship with him.

On the other hand, you could provide him with a gated VNC view of your software, whereby he can use it but where you remain in control of the environment.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I've used [Zelix KlassMaster](http://www.zelix.com/) to perform obfuscation.  It does a very good job, however, you have to spend time to configure it such that it works properly for your needs.  If you use reflection, then you have to ensure that it doesn't obfuscate those class/method/property names, etc.  One of its strong suits is that it will obfuscate strings as well.

All that being said, the end result is that your client will still have your code, alebit in a very difficult-to-understand format.  However, if he truly has the time and effort, he can reverse engineer it.

A lot also depends on exactly what it is that you are trying to protect.  If you are trying to protect the actual IP then obfuscation will help you out.  If you are trying to protect licensing, then obfuscation just makes it a little more challenging for someone to figure out where your licencing module(s) are and how to circumvent them.  In the latter case, I would then suggest that you use something like [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) to weave in licensing checks in several different classes just to make it more difficult to break.  However that too is not fail-proof.

As others have already said, the only fool-proof system is to not give the client the code in the first place and change to a SAAS (Service as a software) solution.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a modified classloader that is able to load your classes from an encrypted storage. As you do not directly expose the jar and the classes inside it might help but as all others said above - it won't be bulletproof.